# Prowide library exception while processing ISO 20022 messages with Dates

Tags: java

We are encountering the following difficulty processing ISO 20022 messages with dates on them.

Considering this sese.024.001.10 message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataPDU xmlns="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <Body>                 
        <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">                         
            <Fr>                                 
                <FIId>                                         
                    <FinInstnId>                                                 
                        <BICFI>DCVBCOBOXXX</BICFI> <!--BIC de la entidad que envía el mensaje-->
                        <Othr>                                                         
                            <Id>DCVBCOBOXXX</Id> <!--BIC del DCV-->
                        </Othr>                                         
                    </FinInstnId>                                 
                </FIId>                         
            </Fr>                         
            <To>                                 
                <FIId>                                         
                    <FinInstnId>                                                 
                        <BICFI>IMF1COBOXXX</BICFI> <!--BIC de la entidad que recibe el mensaje-->
                        <Othr>                                                         
                            <Id>DCVBCOBOXXX</Id> <!--BIC del DCV-->
                        </Othr>                                         
                    </FinInstnId>                                 
                </FIId>                         
            </To>                         
            <BizMsgIdr>20200818X0000121</BizMsgIdr> <!--ID del mensaje-->
            <MsgDefIdr>sese.024.001.10</MsgDefIdr> <!--Tipo de mensaje enviado-->
            <CreDt><!--2020-08-18T09:08:30Z--></CreDt> <!--Fecha y hora de creación del mensaje-->
        </AppHdr>                 
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sese.024.001.10">                         
            <SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>                                 
                <TxId>
                    <AcctOwnrTxId>115</AcctOwnrTxId><!--Referencia de transacción informada en el tag TxId del mensaje sese.023-->
                    <AcctSvcrTxId>20200818T00052360</AcctSvcrTxId><!--Referencia única de la transacción en el DCV-->
                </TxId>
                <MtchgSts>
                    <Mtchd>MACH</Mtchd><!--Indicador de que la transacción se encuentra emparejada-->
                </MtchgSts>
                <TxDtls>
                    <TradDt>
                        <Dt>
                            <DtTm>2020-08-18T08:01:30</DtTm><!--Fecha y hora de negociación informada en el mensaje sese.023-->
                        </Dt>
                    </TradDt>
                </TxDtls>
            </SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>                 
        </Document>         
    </Body>
</DataPDU>
```

We try to make a JSon object out of it using Prowide this way:

MxSese02400110 prowideFuncional=MxSese02400110.parse(message);
System.out.println(prowideFuncional.toJson());

But every time the toJson() method is called, we get a the exception Unable to make public com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl() accessible: module java.xml does not "exports com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype" to unnamed module

And this only happens when the XML has any dates on it.

If i remove them, leave them in blank or comment them (in this case TAGs DtTm and CreDt)  the Exception goes away.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is MxSese02400110 your class, or does it come from a third party?  That class (or a class it’s using) is using inappropriate reflection.  That needs to be fixed, if you have the power to do so.

Comment: Hi The class is embedded on the library package, included with Prowide.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not your input message.  The problem is the `MxSese02400110` class and the library that contains it.

That library (or a library it uses;  without a stack trace, it’s hard to be certain) is stupidly and foolishly relying on reflection of internal Java SE classes.  This was never appropriate and Sun/Oracle have always advised programmers never to do it.  The Java compiler has emitted warnings for such code for the last several years.  (I don’t understand why the library is doing it in this case;  there are public factory methods for creating XMLGregorianCalendar objects, which would require no reflective hacks at all.)

The ideal solution is to make the vendor fix their code.  But I’m guessing that isn’t a realistic option here.

You will have to add some JVM options to your program.

You should be able to fix it by forcing Java’s internal module to be accessible to other classes, using the command-line option `--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype=ALL-UNNAMED`.  I don’t think it’s possible to do this in code at runtime, but I may be wrong.

You may also need to *open* the module, to allow the `MxSese02400110` class to make the Java SE module’s internal classes accessible.  That would be done with an additional command-line option: `--add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype=ALL-UNNAMED`  (Notice that it’s `--add-opens` unlike the first option which which is `--add-exports`.)

In summary, if you are running your program from a terminal or command window, you want to add these options when you run `java` or `java.exe` (or `javaw.exe`):

```
--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype=ALL-UNNAMED
```

If you are running from a container like GlassFish, JBoss, Tomcat, etc., you will need to modify the startup script for that container and add those JVM options to it.

Comment: Finally solved the issue going to 1.8 compiler. It looks like the library is not fully compatible with Java versions going beyond 8.

Comment: Hi Leon, I'm part of Prowide. The library works just fine on Java above 8. Notice starting on Java 9 the jaxb libraries are no longer included by default. You have to either enable the module, or to add a jaxb implementation dependencies.
As for VGR's comment, the JSON conversion is just a call to Gson which indeed does reflection on the model. The model itself, is generated with xic. I'm not sure what fix is being proposed. The XMLGregorianCalendar in the model will be eventually migrated to java.time. As for the xml marshaling, the library already includes pluggable adapters.

Comment: @SebastianZubrinic I may have been unnecessarily harsh.  Updated my wording accordingly.  There is never a valid reason to call setAccessible on the members of an XMLGregorianCalendar implementation, but I don’t know which library is doing it.  This sort of illicit reflection, unfortunately, is the reason so many developers refuse to use a version of Java later than 8.

Comment: @VGR that would be the Google Gson library then. To deal with it, we already have a custom XMLGregorianCalendar adapter in the Prowide library, and we pass it to the Gson engine when serializing the model. Based on this post, it appears that the adapter is not being called as expected. I've created a ticket so it is debugged https://github.com/prowide/prowide-iso20022/issues/60